# Targeting element without ID or Class with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So here the thing, I got something like this:

```
blablabla
lots of code that change from time to time
blablabla

<center>
  <a href="somewhere">
     <img src="someUNIQUEaddress.gif">
  </a>
</center>

blablabla
lots of code that change from time to time
blablabla
```

Now you see, I don't have any access to HTML and I can't use JS. I need somehow to target this, I know there's a way to target something like this:

```
[class="someUNIQUEthing"]
```

So perhaps there's a way like that to target the `src` of the img?

**EDIT**

I did it simply using this:

```
[src="myuniquething"]
```

Comment: Here is the css selector reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: How is that helpful, man? nvmd, solved this out my self

Comment: look for the Edit, mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for a equivalent to `[class='someUNIQUEthing']`. You can use the following:

```css
img[src='someUNIQUEaddress.gif'] {
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src="someUNIQUEaddress.gif">
```

Comment: `UNIQUE` is something that can change (like a random generated string), so you can't write this.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ - you see his edit?? I think he was searching for this!

Comment: NICE Seba! I figured it out my self, but I'll select ur answer mate. BTW, adrenaline, the "unique" means it CAN'T change, 'cause it's unique :)

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this in two ways, as follow, in my code u can compare with any image extension like `.jpg`, `.gif`, `.png` etc

```css
img[src='someUNIQUEaddress.gif'] {
 border:2px solid red;
}

[src$=".gif"] {
   border:2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<img src="someUNIQUEaddress.gif">

<img src="sample.gif">
```